# Can an agent be trained in a completely random environment (the rules and actions stay the same)

Tags: neural-networks, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I am specifically talking about the FrozenLake example from openAI gym to illustrate my question.
https://gym.openai.com/envs/FrozenLake-v0/

The way I understand how Q-Learning or DQL works on the FrozenLake environment is that the agent plays the same map a lot of times until either the Q-table or the NN can approximate the value of a given state action tuple.

However while doing some research, I found no one attempting to try to use the randomly generated map of this environment.

I also dont understand how it would work... It seems to me that an agent only tries to learn the different states of a specific environment. However if this environment changes every time, the agent can not use its previously learned information (e.g. the agent can not remember where the holes are to avoid as they change every time the level is newly generated)...

---

- Is it impossible to train an agent on a changing environment if the observation space is only its current position (but not the whole level) *
- Is it possible to create an agent that can somehow generalise and learn to navigate every random level he is confronted with?

  - If yes, is DQN the right algorithm to do so?
  - If yes, is the solution to give the agent more information about the state (i.e. a bigger observation space) (if  yes, what kind of information could be given additionally? the whole level would be too much because then other algorithms could be used, or not?)
- Am I understanding something else wrong?

---

(*) Intuitively I would say yes, at least in the case of the FrozeLake example. If the only information about the state the algorithm receives is its current position in the state, there should be no way for an agent to predict where a hole could be, so he can only guess where to go and might fall in a hole.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it impossible to train an agent on a changing environment if the observation space is only its current position (but not the whole level)

No, it is possible to learn an optimal policy for the average environment:

To answer this question, let's try to identify the optimal policy first analytically:

According to the linked file:

- The start is always in the top left, the goal is always in the bottom right corner.
- The reward is 1 if we reach the goal, and 0 if we fall into a hole.
- The action space is the cardinal directions, lets assume that the ice is not slippery.

The rest of the tiles are random, but it is guaranteed that we have a possible path from start to finish.

So what is the optimal policy here?

As we can not know the location of the holes, we might as well ignore them, and it becomes apparent that any policy that moves towards the bottom right, i.e. only moves to the bottom and to the right is optimal.

This is quickly illustrated in the [colab I wrote for the task](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1BrM9nXCm7sLva1p3_BHKEkGzh7ylwiNp), which shows that we can learn a policy that is far better than a random agent, even when switching the environment each time.

[image: Results of Sarsa Agent]

The learned policy also looks almost as expected, the top right corner was however visited so infrequently, that the policy is not optimal there:

```
Learned policy (Down, Right, Left, Up):
['D', 'D', 'D', 'U']
['D', 'D', 'D', 'D']
['D', 'D', 'D', 'D']
['R', 'R', 'R', 'D']
```

> Is it possible to create an agent that can somehow generalise and learn to navigate every random level he is confronted with?

No, the best we can do given only the position as observation is to learn an agent that performs optimally on the average task, as above.

> If yes, is the solution to give the agent more information about the state (i.e. a bigger observation space) (if yes, what kind of information could be given additionally? the whole level would be too much because then other algorithms could be used, or not?)

As long as the information is enough to infer the position of the holes, we can learn an optimal policy on every new map, as such the whole map provides sufficient information.

Answer (score 1):

*I will be adding links that I found helpful to answer my question here, while still hoping I will receive an actual answer.*

---

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52744919/is-reinforcement-learning-applicable-to-a-random-environment
This seems to indicate that using a changing or random environment seems to be possible, however difficult and not really feasible with reinforcement learning based algorithms that try to approximate the value of a state, like DQN, ...